# Support of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the definition of support of a continuous function $f:U\to R$ it is said to be the closure ( in $R^n$) of the set $\{x\in U: f(x)\neq 0\}$. So a non-zero constant function defined on $(0,1)$ has support $ [0,1]$. Is this correct. What I mean is, can the support be larger than the domain as is the case above.

Comment: Please provide more context. Where is this definition from? Does $U$ have to be open?

Comment: Yes it is assumed U is open. In one PDE book the closure is in ambient space and in another note on Geometric measure theory it is assumed that the closure is in subspace topology. This is my confusion, which definition  to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various different types of support defined in different contexts, but given what you have described, the following seems to be what you are looking for:

If $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the [(*closed*) *support*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Closed_support) of a continuous map $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is $$\text{supp}\,f:=\overline{\{x\in U:f(x)\neq 0\}}.$$ This closure will be taken *within* $U$, so $\text{supp}\,f$ will be contained in the domain $U$.

More generally, if $X$ is a topological space, then a continuous map $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ has closed support $$\text{supp}\,f:=\overline{\{x\in X:f(x)\neq 0\}},$$ and this closure is taken within the domain $X$, regardless of whether or not it is contained in some larger space.

So the closed support of $x\mapsto 1:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is the closure of $(0,1)$ in $(0,1)$, which of course is $(0,1)$.